# How to get JSLint errors to show up in Eclipse Problems view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana, jslint

I've installed Aptana Studio 3 Plugin (v3.2.2) in Eclipse (STS 3.0, actually) for its JSLint integration.  Any errors/warnings show up fine as markers when I open a particular JavaScript file.  I'd also like JSLint to run at build time and show its output in Eclipse's Problems view, just like Java build errors/warnings.  How do I enable this?